# DPC++ capture this pointer in the kernal function

Tags: c++, lambda, dpc++

When I want to capture the this pointer or outside variable in DPC++ code, I have to write it in my lambda function explicitly

```
class abc{
    queue Q{};
    std::array<int, constsize> e;
    std::array<double, constsize>t;
    abc(){
    ua = malloc_shared<double>(local_size, this->Q);
    }
    
    void b();
    
}

void abc::b(){
      for(int i=0;i<constsize;i++){
      e[i]=i;
      t[i]=2*i; 
      }

    buffer<int> ee{e};
    buffer<double> tt{t};
auto ini2 = this->Q.submit([=,uq=this->ua](handler &h)
            { accessor eee{ee, h, read_only};
              accessor ttt{tt, h, read_only};
                                        
              h.parallel_for(range{size1, size2, size3}, [=](id<3> idx)
              double eu=uq[id[0]];
              int aa=eee[id[1]];
              double cc=ttt[id[2]];
             }

}
```

But, now I have a lot of variables that need to be captured in the lambda function, do I have to use the same method to write them explicitly?

Comment: the question is unclear. In your code you are already using `=` and `&` to capture all by value/reference

Comment: I want to use ua which is declared in the constructor, but without this [&, uq=this->ua], I cannot use ua.

Comment: My bad, I just change it.